# No token in request - Account Linking with new Actions SDK

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I am building an action with the new Actions Builder and everything is going pretty smoothly. I just setup account linking and can successfully link my account, however, once I do link my account there is no token included in the subsequent requests for me to use, even though the account linking status is in the request as "LINKED". Can anyone shed any light on why I am not seeing a token?

For reference, here is a version of one of my requests.

```
{
  "requestJson": {
    "handler": {
      "name": "main"
    },
    "intent": {
      "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
      "params": {},
      "query": "Talk to my new app"
    },
    "scene": {
      "name": "actions.scene.START_CONVERSATION",
      "slotFillingStatus": "UNSPECIFIED",
      "slots": {},
      "next": {
        "name": "ListPrompt"
      }
    },
    "session": {
      "id": "ABwppHE7M6NS8KdyjljEptrtZZ5GkE3qDdaiwjYbL9ehrA-t_c-ZsCrZ_WhN0ZTG5lXXXXXXhU6Im5vgeSwow",
      "params": {},
      "typeOverrides": [],
      "languageCode": ""
    },
    "user": {
      "locale": "en-US",
      "params": {},
      "accountLinkingStatus": "LINKED",
      "verificationStatus": "VERIFIED",
      "packageEntitlements": [],
      "lastSeenTime": "2020-07-13T12:02:42Z"
    },
    "home": {
      "params": {}
    },
    "device": {
      "capabilities": [
        "SPEECH",
        "RICH_RESPONSE",
        "LONG_FORM_AUDIO"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google docs for the Account Linking with the new Actions Builder have now been updated with additional information.  The token is now provided within the headers of the incoming request. Details of how to find and decode this can be found at https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#handle_data_access_requests